# Relationship between two schemas in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have two schemas first one is countrySchema which has country id and name:
Below is the schema code:

```
var countrySchema = new Schema({
        country_id:String,
        country_name:String
});
var countryArray = mongoose.model('countryArray',countrySchema);
```

Another schema is stateSchema which has state id and state name:
below is the schema code:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var stateSchema = new Schema({
        state_id:String,
        state_name:String,
});
var states = mongoose.model('states',stateSchema);
```

Now, in stateSchema i want to have state_id, country_id which is actually coming from the countrySchema and the state_name. How do I do this ?

Comment: Check this, this will help you.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKuY8QscZwY&index=8&list=PL55RiY5tL51q4D-B63KBnygU6opNPFk_q

Answer (score 0):

You can add the country_id as follows and refer the country module in your state module with ObjectId of the country. Then you have to use the objectId which created by mongoose for the particular country as the country_id of stateSchema.

countrySchema

```
var countrySchema = new Schema({
        _id:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        country_id:String,
        country_name:String
});
var countryArray = mongoose.model('countryArray',countrySchema);
```

stateSchema

```
var stateSchema = new Schema({
        _id:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        state_id:String,
        country_id: {Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'countryArray'},
        state_name:String,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This One..

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var countrySchema = new Schema({
        country_id:String,
        country_name:String
});
var countryArray = mongoose.model('countryArray',countrySchema);


var stateSchema = new Schema({
        state_id:String,
        state_name:String,
        country: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'countryArray' },

});
var states = mongoose.model('states',stateSchema);
```